# load css on print this page yii2

Tags: php, css, yii2

I use yii2.
I have a file css like this (for test) and I put them into web/css:

```
body{
   font-family: 'Verdana';
   font-size: 8px;
}

table{
   border : 1px solid black;
}
```

So I register it in _form.php like this :

```
<?php
   $this->registerCssFile("@web/css/struk.css", [
       'media' => 'print'
        ]);
?>

<div class="transaction-form">
     ..............
```

Now, I have button :

```
Html::button('Test Print', ['class' => 'btn  btn-success',
                        'onclick' => 'w = window.open();'
                        . 'w.document.write($("#modalContent").html());'
                        . 'w.print();'
                        . 'w.close();']),
```

But, the css is not working.
Any help it so appreciated.

Comment: try to register css in assets bundle

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to take a look at the order of your CSS file in your `<head></head>` tag? Maybe the order is overriden by Bootstrap (i assume you use this based on your button class).

Also, you can check using Firefox/Chrome inspect element to know how the style works for each of your element, what file override your file, and etc.

That's why my suggestion is try to put the css in the Asset Bundle, and take care of it dependencies.

Another thought, you use `'media' => 'print'` which means your CSS may also work on only printed screen. Of cource it won't be displayed in your browser directly.